# &#x00A0 and &nbsp; not working in iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad

I have a problem in my nav menu in my website responsive... when I check to iPad, the indention using `&#x00A0` and `&nbsp;` were not working.

```
el.find('a').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
    optText = "&nbsp;&nbsp;" + $this.text(),
    optSub = $this.parents( '.' + settings.subMenuClass ),
    len = optSub.length,
    dash;
    ...
```

I tried `&nbsp;`

```
if( $this.parents('ul ul ul').hasClass( settings.subMenuClass ) ) {
    dash = Array( len+1 ).join( settings.subMenuDash );
    optText = '&nbsp; &nbsp; ' + optText;
}
```

and `&#x00A0`

```
if( $this.parents('ul ul ul').hasClass( settings.subMenuClass ) ) {
    dash = Array( len+1 ).join( settings.subMenuDash );
    optText = '&#x00A0 &#x00A0 ' + optText;
}
```

both were not working on iPad, but the other devices and browsers were great.

Does anyone have an idea about my case? Thanks in advance...

Comment: What function do you use when setting optText?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$(this).html()`. Since that `&nbsp;` and `&#x00A0;` are HTML entities, they will not be parsed if you put the `optText` variable in the `.text()` of the element.

You have to use `optText = $(this).html()` to read it and `$(this).html(optText)` to assign it:

```
function() ...
    var optText = $(this).html(); // read the text
    ...
    $(this).html('&nbsp;&nbsp; ' + optText); // replace the text adding the indention
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replace `&#x00A0` and `&nbsp;` with `&zwnj;` then it works...